# How can I specify the minor version of a .Net 6 target application to 6.0.1

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, .net-6.0

I have a .Net 6 application that is deployed to a large number of desktops. Our IT infrastructure team installs a specific version of the .Net 6 (6.0.1)

When I compile this in Visual Studio or in a Azure DevOps pipeline the latest available .Net 6 version is taken. This is problematic because we don't want to keep on updating the .Net6 version on our many desktops

In the csproj file

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Ideally I would like to specify something like

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows;netcoreapp6.0.1</TargetFramework>
```

But this does not work. How can I specify that the target should be .Net 6.0.1 in Visual Studio or in the Build step in my Build Pipeline?

Comment: I would like to avoid using a self contained deployment

Answer (score 2):

In Azure DevOps pipeline, the [Use .NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) may help you. You can add this task before build.

> Use this task to acquire a specific version of .NET Core from the
> Internet or the tools cache and add it to the PATH.
>
> You can also use this task to **change the version of .NET Core used in
> subsequent tasks like .NET Core cli task**.

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 6.0.1
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

Comment: Great idea, although I had to specify version 6.0.100 for it to work. The problem is that if I use dotPeek on the resulting DLL I get my.App (5.4.0.1453, msil, .NETCoreApp v6.0.2) so all it did was specify exactly the SDK but still took the latest available version instead of v6.0.1